# redux-saga, TypeError: (0 , _effects.takeLatest) is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm beginning with `redux-saga`. I can't figure out what I do wrong.

`webpack` compile succeeded. My app can run, but chrome gives me this error.

And dispatch action doesn't work.

`node v6.6.0`

`saga/Beginning.js`:

```js
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

//api service
const api = 'http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1';

const service = {};

service.fetchBook = function(query) {
  const url = `${api}/search/${query}`;
  return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
};

function* fetchBook(action) {
  try {
    const books = yield call(service.fetchBook, action.payload.query);
    yield put({ type: 'BOOK_FETCH_SUCCEEDED', books });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: 'BOOK_FETCH_FAILED', message: e.message });
  }
}

function* watchFetchBook() {
  yield takeEvery('BOOK_FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchBook);
}

function* watchFetchBook() {
  yield takeLatest('BOOK_FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchBook);
}

export default watchFetchBook;
```

`saga/index.js`

```js
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import Beginning from './Beginning';

export default function* root() {
  yield [fork(Beginning)];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`takeLatest` doesn't belongs to Redux Saga effects ([see reference](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takelatestpattern-saga-args)), you have to import it using

```js
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga'
```

instead of

```js
import {takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends,

if redux-saga version < [0.14](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v0.14.0) then

```js
import { takeEvery, takeLatest, throttle } from 'redux-saga';
```

else

```js
import { takeEvery, takeLatest, throttle } from 'redux-saga/effects';
```

[reference](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1279):

> import { takeEvery, takeLatest, throttle } from 'redux-saga' was
>   deprecated already since [0.14](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v0.14.0) which got out nearly a year ago.